# Open downloaded file in browser pdf format

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pdfkit

I am using paperclip to upload docx doc and pdf files to my railsapp, is there any way I can view this uploaded files in the browser itself in pdf format, without downloading it ?

Comment: Have you looked at prawn2?

Comment: And have you tried anything out?

Comment: prawn2 wont serve my purpose here I want to open the file which i have uploaded on the app it could be doc or docx file

Answer (score 0):

Try [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/).
Firefox recently started using it as viewer for PDF files, but you can integrate it in your app. But you still need to 'download' it, that is, load into the browser.